# How make luaenv and luarocks play together correctly

Tags: lua, luarocks

Me using [anyenv](https://github.com/mislav/anyenv) for installing all scripting languages versions. Currently using it for perl `plenv`, node `ndenv`, python `pyenv` and just installed the [luaenv](https://github.com/cehoffman/luaenv) too. Great, because doesn't pollute the system dirs - everything is installed to my *user defined* directory.

The `luaenv` is installed OK, and i could:

```
$ luaenv install 5.1.5   #installed OK
$ luaenv global 5.1.5    #OK
$ luaenv which lua
/opt/anyenv/envs/luaenv/versions/5.1.5/bin/lua
$ luaenv versions
* 5.1.5 (set by /opt/anyenv/envs/luaenv/version)
$ lua -v
Lua 5.1.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2012 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
```

Looks that everything is OK.

Of course want install `luarocks` too. Unfortunatey, the `luaenv` itself doesn't provides support for the installtion of the `luarocks`, (e.g. missing the `luaenv install-rocks` or something like for the perl: `plenv install-cpanm`) - so tried follow the [quick-start guide](https://luarocks.org/#quick-start), e.g.:

- download the sources
- `./configure`
- `make build`

The configure failed with the message about the missing `lua.h`.

```
Checking Lua includes... 
lua.h not found (looked in /opt/anyenv/envs/luaenv/include, /opt/anyenv/envs/luaenv/include/lua/5.1, /opt/anyenv/envs/luaenv/include/lua5.1)
You may want to use the flag --with-lua or --with-lua-include. See --help.
```

So, the first bug: the `luaenv` isn't sets the correct paths. :(

After the:

```
$ find /opt/anyenv/envs/luaenv -name lua.h -print
/opt/anyenv/envs/luaenv/versions/5.1.5/include/lua.h
```

tried again with:

```
$ ./configure --with-lua=/opt/anyenv/envs/luaenv/versions/5.1.5
```

Now it finishes successfully, so followed with the `make build`.

Checked the result, of the build in the `src/luarocks/site_config.lua`

```
local site_config = {}
site_config.LUAROCKS_PREFIX=[[/usr/local]]
site_config.LUA_INCDIR=[[/opt/anyenv/envs/luaenv/versions/5.1.5/include]]
site_config.LUA_LIBDIR=[[/opt/anyenv/envs/luaenv/versions/5.1.5/lib]]
site_config.LUA_BINDIR=[[/opt/anyenv/envs/luaenv/versions/5.1.5/bin]]
site_config.LUAROCKS_SYSCONFDIR=[[/usr/local/etc/luarocks]]
site_config.LUAROCKS_ROCKS_TREE=[[/usr/local]]
site_config.LUAROCKS_ROCKS_SUBDIR=[[/lib/luarocks/rocks]]
site_config.LUA_DIR_SET=true
site_config.LUAROCKS_UNAME_S=[[Darwin]]
site_config.LUAROCKS_UNAME_M=[[x86_64]]
site_config.LUAROCKS_DOWNLOADER=[[curl]]
site_config.LUAROCKS_MD5CHECKER=[[md5sum]]
return site_config
```

Which is clearly WRONG. The paths shold NOT point to the `/usr/local` but somewhere into the versioned directories managed by the `luaenv`.

I'm an lua-noob. Trying to learn it. But i'm unable to set even the basic environment. :( After a hour of googling giving up and asking here:

**How to configure and install `luarocks` to play correctly with the `luaenv` and the `lua` versions installed by the `luaenv`?**

Comment: Taking a look at LuaRocks source code, it seems it would possible to pass several knobs to the "configure" script. For instance, "./configure --prefix "<path>" --sysconfdir "<path>" --rocks-tree "<path">. Would that work?